# My heir is unfit for the throne. How can I make him aware of this fact?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I have a heir whose stats are really bad.  Seeing as how my ruler is still young, I have a large chance of having another child.

Is it possible to <strike>kill</strike> render him unfit for duty? Either through spy actions or a console command?

Comment: Hey, @iber.  I edited your question a little, and might have changed the meaning in the process.  If you don't like it, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: Crap, disregard my close vote. I failed to look at the tags properly until just as I pushed the button. Have a +1 instead!

Comment: @fbueckert Oh *sweet*. Too bad it's not implemented on mobile yet, or I might have noticed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are no direct covert actions that will let you kill your heir. However, do not lose hope, for there is still a chance at murder.

- There are a few random events that can either: a) let you choose an option that kills your heir or, b) simply kills your heir (the hunting accident event, for example)

A much more direct approach:

- You can assign your heir to become a general in the Military tab. Then, put him in command of a thousand brave troops and send him to war against an overwhelming enemy. Repeat until he is dead.

With the Rights of Man DLC enabled:

- A country may disinherit an heir if so is wished, at a cost of 50 prestige. After this action is done the country won't have any legal heir and will be at risk of falling under a Personal Union, just like any other country without a legal heir (It is not possible to "return" to the disinherited heir).

Comment: Ah, the Uriah gambit...

Comment: So my hier will be very brave in battles... ;)

Answer (score 11):

If you don't mind using cheats, there's a console command: `kill_heir`

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. The question specifically asks for console commands, so it can certainly at least be listed here. You don't have to use it if you don't like it.

Answer (score -2):

Make your heir a general. Let him lead an army of 1000, put the army on a fleet of a single transport, and send the fleet into open ocean and watch the attrition destroy it.

Comment: This merely repeats another answer.